# Как обрабатывать данные используя node streams?

Tags: node.js, потоки-данных

Не могу понять как обрабатывать, работать с данными в чанках. Допустим у меня есть огромный массив с массивами и мне нужно сделать массив с объектами, т.е. нужно как то отлавливать каждый массив и переделывать его в объект . Но как? Если данные рандомно обрываются

Comment: В общем как обработать большой JSON, что то добавить изменить и т.д..
Как я могу применять JSON.parse, если данные будут разбиты на фрагменты памяти?

Comment: никак. JSON не предназначен для стриминга. Либо писать свой парсер, либо искать готовый. Например https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream